# How to change spring boot active profiles on EnvironmentPostProcessor?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have implemented a custom `EnvironmentPostProcessor` to set the value of specific properties programmatically in my spring boot application. My code is run after `application.yml` properties are read, but before dependency injection, solving part of my problem.

However, besides setting additional variables, ideally I want to change the spring active profile set in my `EnvironmentPostProcessor` implementation. This is a problem, as the profile would be set after the properties have already been read from the yml config.

Is there some easy way of reloading all the properties using a new set of profiles in my `EnvironmentPostProcessor` implementation?

Comment: check `AbstractEnvironment` in spring there you can configure profile and also reload properties.

Comment: I have set the profile using this class, but I was unable to find how to reload the properties.

Comment: did you tried overriding `customizePropertySources` method?

Comment: @RaghvendraGarg how you are suggesting extending the AbstractEnvironment to override  customizePropertySources?
I am stuck on same issue now. This issue seems to be not closed.